# Efecto blur no deja mostrar texto

Tags: html, css

Tengo un círculo, el cual tiene un efecto `blur()`, pero dentro de ese circulo tengo un texto, y al momento de colocar el `blur()` desaparece el texto ya que esta dentro del `div` que crea el círculo.

```css
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    left: 300px;
    top: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.6);
    filter: blur(25px);  
}
    
h2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding:3%;
    color: #F6C122;
    font-family: kurale;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
    <div class="circle">
        <h2 >HI!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quiero que arriba de este circulo con blur tenga el texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Realmente querés un blur? ¿O solo querés una sombra? Para eso podrías usar un `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro de si es posible eliminar que afecte a los objetos hijos, pero yo optaria por algo diferente, en vez de crear un elemento crear dos, darle blur a uno superponerlo hasta atrás y darle un efecto diferente al segundo elemento, algo como esto.

```css
.padre {
  position: relative;
}
.blur {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.6);
    filter: blur(25px);
    z-index: 2;   
}
.no-blur {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.no-blur h2 {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="blur">
  </div>
  <div class="no-blur">
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sí es posible al utilizar `:before`

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo puedes lograr al modificar `circle:before` en lugar de `circle` de esa forma te aseguras que el `blur` se aplique únicamente al `div` con la clase `circle` y no al contenido.

Ejemplo:

```css
.circle:before {
  content: "";
  
  position: absolute;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
    
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;

  display: block;
  background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.6);
  
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    left: 300px;
    top: 15px;
}
    
h2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding:3%;
    color: #F6C122;
    font-family: kurale;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
    <div class="circle">
        <h2 >HI!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```